# iMac 21.5″ Wi-Fi Issues

Tags: network, wifi, imac, airport

My iMac constantly dropping its internet connection in the last couple of days. I'm connected to a 2.4GHZ Airport Express. Not a router issue, because my iPhone and iPad works just fine, no connectivity issues. Also not an iMac hardware issue, because i tried to connect to the iPhone's tethering network using WiFi, works just fine, without any issues. Here is a copy/paste from the network utility when i try to ping google, you can see that the network is dropping constantly:

http://pastebin.com/TL3UyQif

You can see that the ping time increases just before and after the connection lost. Driving me nuts.

I know theres multiple questions like this, but i seriously tried every solution from these question, but nothing helps:

- Pinging in the background to keep the connection
- Tried deleting all network preferences, setup new network
- Deleting wifi keychains
- Upgrade & Downgrade Airport Express firmware
- Changed the channel number to 11
- Tried with closed iTunes
- Tried different browser
- PRam reset
- Tried renaming the SSID
- Connecting to 5GHZ network
- No torrent running in the background
- Tried with Google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)
- Changed MTU to 1453
- Disconnected both my iPad and iPhone from wifi, so only my iMac uses the network, no luck

If i disable wifi and turn it back on, it will **ALWAYS** fix the issue for a couple of seconds/minutes, but if i don't do anything, usually it will fixes itself in a minute or two.

OSX 10.9.4
21.5-inch iMac, Mid 2011

Not sure if it helps, but a couple of more stuff:
I used the Wireless Diagnostics to get the following stuff:

- wifi.log: http://pastebin.com/svNJhNNr
- Available networks: http://cl.ly/image/3a1n1X3X023E
- Performance: http://cl.ly/image/0v3f0d3H1B1p

Edit: Just updated to 10.10 (14A299l), same issue, even when it asked me for my iCloud login on the first startup, it won't accept it because the connection lost...

Comment: Feel free to give me any tips what else should i provide in the question to help diagnose this issue.

Comment: you did a lot of work already! did you check this article http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4628

Comment: Is there any chance you are not dropping the connection but, instead, having the wireless card just "turning off?" If so are you able to just get it back on or must you restart the computer to get it back on and connected again?